# (Angular) How can I dynamically insert an <img> tag into a <pre> tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using Angular6.

I have a pre tag with email text. Within this email text are tags like `[cid:image001.jpg]` which represent an image, using `image001.jpg`, I can retrieve that specific image from the back-end.

The problem is that I don't know how I can insert a new HTML element from the Typescript file into the pre tag, if this is even possible.

I have tried using a `replace()` method and replacing the `'[cid:image001.jpg]'` with `'<img ...>'` but it (understandably) gets interpreted as a string.

Help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

the positioning of the images is important, the `<img>` tag should appear where the `[cid:image001.jpg]` is, for example.

**Example email:**

> Greetings,
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
>   vehicula egestas elit viverra auctor.  [cid:image001.jpg] Morbi at
>   nisi vel lorem porta pellentesque ut non urna.
>
> Integer tempor tincidunt viverra. Vivamus ullamcorper et risus ac.
>   [cid:image002.jpg]
>
> Best regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following, I changed:

```
<pre> {{emailText}} </pre>
```

To:

```
<pre innerHTML="safeHTML(emailText)"> </pre>
```

Where `safeHTML()` cleans the text so that scripting is not possible, this is important because it would be very unsafe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to pass the image in argument like this:

`<img [cid]="pictureUrl">`

Comment: I understand what you're saying but that is not what I meant. I think I may have been unclear. The positioning of the image is important, I could use your strategy if I could place them all at the bottom for example but I want to display the images where they are in the original email. I don't think that is possible with your strategy.